# defining a group of services to run with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, configuration, shortcut

I'm wondering if there is a method to define, and launch, a group of services configured in a docker-compose.yml file.

To make a real world example, I'm working with laradock: it has a lot of services configured (I think more than 50) - You have to "select" which one to run every time.

In fact to run a normal php + apache + mysql stack, you can use:

`docker compose up workspace apache2 mysql`

**The final question is**: can those three services be grouped under an alias, like "amp" and this alias used to launch these services with:

`docker compose up amp` ?

---

*What I have tried, already*

I thought about duplicating the docker-compose.yml into a simpler one, where only the required services are present.

Anyway this configuration I'm using (laradock) it's quite complex, being able to define an alias, would lead to a much easier to handle configuration.

Imagine the case where you need to add one more service to the group: instead of doing cut & paste of it's configuration(s), you just add it's name, and nothing else.

Is this possibile somehow?

Thank you

Comment: If the `workspace` service `depends_on: [apache2, mysql]` then `docker-compose up workspace` will bring those other services with it.  But otherwise this might be a scale where your workload is a little bigger than can comfortably be managed by Compose (and for that matter might not fit on a single host!) and larger-scale solutions like Kubernetes could be a good match.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way that might do what you want is to create an `alias` for your shell/terminal. To do that in a "permanent" way you might need to edit the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files. For reference you can check, for example, this link [here](https://jonsuh.com/blog/bash-command-line-shortcuts/).

That way if you want to change the services of a "group" (which will be defined by the `alias`), you will just need to edit the line for that `alias` in the file.

Comment: This is a nice solution!